# Tests not passing in Rspec in CodeWars

Tags: ruby

> Your task in this kata is to implement a function that, given a list of pepes (`pepes`), returns the rarest pepe in the list. If two or more pepes are equally rare, return a list of these pepes, sorted in alphabetical order. Also, if the rarest pepe (or pepes) has a frequency of 5 or more, then it is not really a rare pepe, so your function should return `'No rare pepes!'`.

I have my code:

```
def find_rarest_pepe(pepes)
  x = pepes.select {|x| pepes.count(x) == 1}.sort
    if x.count == 1
     return x.join
  elsif
     x.count >= 2
     return x
  else
     return "No rare pepes!"
   end
end
```

However, what am I doing wrong here?

Material: `https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-rarest-pepe/train/ruby`

Comment: Why are you assuming that the minimum count is 1? It could be that the rarest has 3 occurrences, for example.

Comment: Your right, I just assumed it would be one.

Comment: my code seems to pass most tests though, now I realize why they aren't all passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should sort unique pepes by count of occurency, then take count of rarest (first) pepe and select all pepes having this count:

```
def find_rarest_pepe(pepes)
  return 'No rare pepes!' if pepes.empty?

  sorted_pepes = pepes.uniq.map { |pepe| [pepe, pepes.count(pepe)] }.sort_by(&:last)
  rarest_pepe_count = sorted_pepes[0][1]

  return 'No rare pepes!' if rarest_pepe_count >= 5

  rarest_pepes = sorted_pepes.select { |_, pepe_count| pepe_count == rarest_pepe_count }
  rarest_pepes = rarest_pepes.map(&:first).sort
  rarest_pepes = rarest_pepes[0] if rarest_pepes.count == 1
  rarest_pepes
end
```